# Series EE bond $50.00 - what is it worth now? U.S. saving bond

Tags: bonds

What would a $50.00 Series EE bond be worth now if I purchased it in December 1996?

Comment: Not asked, but EE from that timeframe had 20+10 maturity, so they will stop increasing in value after 2026.

Answer (score 5):

You can go to the link below to find out

https://www.treasurydirect.gov/BC/SBCPrice